# Get total in other row and total in column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following need, I need to obtain the totals of both the columns and the rows, then I leave the code that I am using and also some images, thank you very much for the help.

```sql
    SELECT DDF.Codigo,
                    ISNULL((SELECT 
                              COUNT(Codigo)
                              FROM Detalle_
                              WHERE 1=1
                              AND Fecha_i >= @FECHA_INICIO
                              AND Fecha_i <= @FECHA_FIN
                              AND Estado = @ESTADO_N
                              AND  Codigo = DDF.Codigo
                              GROUP BY Codigo),0)Cantidad_No,

                    ISNULL((SELECT 
                              COUNT(Codigo)
                              FROM Detalle_
                              WHERE 1=1
                              AND Fecha_in >= @FECHA_INICIO
                              AND Fecha_in <= @FECHA_FIN
                              AND Estado = @ESTADO_C
                              AND  Codigo = DDF.Codigo
                              GROUP BY Codigo),0)Cantidad_C

        FROM Detalle_ DDF
        WHERE 1=1
                AND DDF.Fecha_i >= @FECHA_INICIO
                AND DDF.Fecha_i <= @FECHA_FIN
        GROUP BY Codigo
```

[image: Now I have this]

[image: This is what I need]

Thanks.

Comment: Snippets don't work with SQL. Please **don't** use images for code, data or errors. Use formatted/tabular text. You would normally calculate such totals in your application/front-end.

Comment: @DaleK It is only my second question in this great community, I appreciate your message and I will take it into account for future opportunities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
    DDF.Codigo,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Estado = @ESTADO_N THEN 1 END) Cantidad_No,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Estado = @ESTADO_C THEN 1 END) Cantidad_C,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN Estado = @ESTADO_N THEN 1 END) + COUNT(CASE WHEN Estado = @ESTADO_C THEN 1 END) Total_

FROM Detalle_ DDF
WHERE DDF.Fecha_i >= @FECHA_INICIO
      AND DDF.Fecha_i <= @FECHA_FIN
 GROUP BY Codigo
```

If you would like to have a total across the whole rowset, use `rollup`:

```sql
....
GROUP BY ROLLUP (Codigo)
```

Comment: this was what i was looking for, that rollup, many many many thanks

Comment: use the following at the beginning, so that the column does not appear in null, and additionally use the rollup, this helped me a lot                                                  
                                                                                                                         
COALESCE (DDF.Codigo, 'Total') Codigo

Answer (score 0):

For achieve right column with total, you have to sum them. For achieving bottom row with total, you have to UNION them. But, as mentioned in the comments, it is preferable to do them in the UI.

```sql
declare @TABLE table(codigo int, cantidad_no int, cantidad_c int) 

insert into @TABLE 
VALUES
(1,20,30), (1,20,50),(2,30,30), (2,30, 20);

select cast(codigo as varchar(20)) as codigo, sum(cantidad_no) as codigo_no, sum(cantidad_c) as codigo_c, cast(sum(cantidad_no)+ sum(cantidad_c) as varchar(20)) as total_  from @TABLE
group by codigo
UNION ALL
select 'Total' AS codigo, sum(cantidad_no), sum(cantidad_c), '' as total_  from @TABLE
```

| codigo | codigo_no | codigo_c | total_ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | 80 | 120 |
| 2 | 60 | 50 | 110 |
| Total | 100 | 130 |  |

**NB:** Remember to cast the values to VARCHAR datatype, so that only you can have integer values & 'Total' in the same column.

Comment: `group by rollup(codigo)` gets the job done faster and easier than messing about with `union all`

Comment: @Charlieface, yes. but, he wants to have Total as the value for column1. so, went for UNION ALL approach

Comment: You can just `isnull` it. Have you ever used `rollup`?

Comment: @Charlieface, yes. I have used. I did not try for this sample. get your point. I also thought of GROUPING SETS . but, i thought that single UNION ALL in this case, as we need only one more row

Comment: Thank you very much for investing your time in trying to help me, I was reviewing and it did not work as I wanted. Anyway, it is a great contribution and I appreciate it.